# Speed of tasks for different factions in The Settlers 2

Tags: the-settlers

In *The Settlers 2*, the different factions appear to have buildings that perform their core functions at different speeds compared to each others' equivalent.  However, this difference in speed seems to be based off of the physical positioning of interactive areas on the buildings and how the settlers walk around it, as opposed to a simple timing variable, making measuring difficult.

**What are the relative speeds of the various tasks between the factions?**  For example, do the factions take different amounts of time to saw boards into planks at a sawmill, or bake bread at a bakery, and if so, how much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this unofficial [Settlers 2 FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/198587-the-settlers-ii/faqs/23599) the is no difference between the factions.

As seen in chapter 2.7, "CIVILISATIONS/PEOPLE"

> There are  NO  differences between the races.  The buildings and the people
>   are the same... unfortunatley.  They  may  look  different but the economic
>   system is identical.

Comment: Well, I don't particularly trust this source as being authoritative, but it is the best answer for now.

Comment: What's your proof for doubting?